# Which constitutes fluid intelligence more, inductive or deductive reasoning?

Tags: intelligence

What is the correlation between these types of reasoning with fluid intelligence? Deductive reasoning is closely related to logic and mathematical proof whereas inductive reasoning is more of a statistical predictive tool, that is, a tool that makes inferences based on observation of data rather than facts. It is not clear that deductive reasoning constitutes a more causal relationship with fluid intelligence. Fluid intelligence is defined as the efficiency with which one acquires skill. Since inductive reasoning is 'easier', a good inductive reasoning individual can acquire knowledge much more efficiently, since it is quicker and requires less cognitive load, whereas deductive reasoning is much slower, requiring a comprehensive set of facts before making judgments.

Humans tend to be better at one rather than the other, with some excelling at both, however, there are individuals with high fluid intelligence possessing high inductive reasoning abilities with low deductive abilities, and also vice versa.

Hence, which has a stronger relationship with g?.

Comment: Is there a physiological difference between inductive and deductive reasoning?  Academics definitely do make a distinction but is it real?  Inductive reasoning frequently deals with looking at anecdotal evidence and drawing a conclusion.  Does this line of reasoning use different mechanisms within our brains?  I posit that it may not.